# Handle nil value in Swift for NSString

Tags: ios, swift, nsstring, option-type

The following method is called a lot from Objective-C files (it's a mixed Obj-C and Swift project) and under certain circumstances I seem to get a nil value for an NSString that throws an exception. According to [this post](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/5008#10042) Swift implicitly converts an NSString to a force unwrapped String!.  How can I handle a nil case

Should I use an if let statement?  If so, what would the syntax be?  I can't get it to work.

```
@objc func download(surl: NSString, completion : @escaping (NSData) -> Void ) {
        
        guard let url = URL(string: String(surl)) else {
            //print("Can not get url with " , surl )
            return }
        
        let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)
        
       
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            if let data = data, error == nil {
                let nsdata = NSData(data: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(nsdata)
                }
            } else {
                
               // print("Failure: %@", error?.localizedDescription);
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: i see this code is safe from crashes but not from nils this strongly depend on the validity of your url/data

Comment: Are you sure that it's the NSString that is nil and not the URL? I wouldn't have thought that would be possible given an NSString parameter—only an *optional* NSString? value should be allowed to be nil. Perhaps the string that you're getting (*surl*) is just an invalid URL?

Comment: by string.count if you have 0 count then string must be empty or nil. so you can apply string.count in your code to identify string nil or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you even using `Objective-C` types with `Swift`? You could have simply used `String` instead of `NSString` and `Data` instead of `NSData`.

```
@objc func download(surl: String?, completion: ((Data?)->())?) {
    guard let str = surl, let url = URL(string: str) else {
        //print("Can not get url with " , surl )
        return
    }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
            completion?(nil)
            return
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion?(data)
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Also, you can use `URSession.shared` object in case there is no specific networking requirement.

Comment: The method is called from Obj-C files...I changed question to show this and we also index downloaded files with NSString which I don't think you can do using String. However changing NSString to String may be the answer.  Will try to get it to work.